# Прочитать содержи мое файла и записать его в массив строк. Вывести строки на экран, убрав все комментарии

Tags: c++, файлы

*Задание:* В файле хранится текст программы на языке С из произвольного количества строк
(длина каждой строки не более 80 символов). Прочитать содержи
мое файла и записать его в массив строк. Вывести строки на экран, убрав все комментарии. Организовать обработку ошибок и некорректного ввода.

Возникла проблема при разработке функции DeleteSlash. Я перепробовал много вариантов её написания, но всё бесполезно, помогите, пожалуйста!

*Код:*

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char ** OpenDataFile (char *filepath, int& n)
{
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen(filepath, "r");
        if (!fp)
        {
                printf ("Error while openning file\n");
                return NULL;
        }
        
        char buffer[81];
        for(;fgets(buffer,81,fp); n++);
        printf("count = %d",n);
        char **arrayStr;
        arrayStr = (char**)malloc(n*sizeof(char*));
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
        {
            arrayStr[i] = (char*)malloc(81*sizeof(char));
        }
        fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_SET);
        
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
            fgets(arrayStr[i],81,fp);
        }
        fclose(fp);
        return arrayStr;
}

void DeleteSlash (char** arrayStrIn, int n)
{
    
    char** arrayStrOut;
    arrayStrOut = (char**)malloc(n*sizeof(char*));
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        arrayStrOut[i] = (char*)malloc(81*sizeof(char));
    }
    
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 81; j++)
        {
            
            while (!((arrayStrIn[i][j] == '/') && (arrayStrIn[i][j++] == '/'))) arrayStrOut[i][j] = arrayStrIn[i][j];
            
        }
    }
        
}

int WriteResultFile(char * filename, char** arrayStr, int n)
{
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen(filename, "w");
        if (!fp)
        {
            printf ("Error while opennin file\n");
            return -1;
        }
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
            fputs(arrayStr[i], fp);
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    
    char filepath[] = "LABTEXT.txt";
    char filepath2[] = "text.txt";
    int len=0;
    char** text = OpenDataFile(filepath, len);
    DeleteSlash (text, len);
    WriteResultFile (filepath2, text, len);
    return 0;
}
```

На данном этапе при запуске программы зависает консольное окно и в файл не выводится ничего.
Пробовал и такой вариант:

```
void DeleteSlash (char** arrayStrIn, int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 81; j++)
        {
            if ((arrayStrIn[i][j] == '/') && (arrayStrIn[i][j++] == '/')) break;
            arrayStrIn[i][j] = arrayStrIn[i][j];            
        }
    }       
}
```

В файле дан такой текст (содержимое файла **LAB.txt**):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

char * inputString (); //прототип функции
void outputString (char * );

int main () {
// вызов функции
    char * str2 = inputString();
//  DoSomething (str);
//реализуем функцию вывода строки на экран  
    outputString (str2);

    return 0;
    }
    
    
    char * inputString () {
    char * str; // объявление указателя
    //c
    str = (char *)malloc(250*sizeof(char)); //sizeof для того, чтобы на любом компе программа работала независимо от размерности типа char
    // тут было выбелено 250 байт памяти
   //free(str); // осовобождение неиспользованной памяти
   scanf("%s", str);
   
//работа с указателями 1 вариант

   for (int i=0; str[i]!='\0'; i++){
    if (str[i]=='A') str[i]='H';
   }
   
// работа с указателями правильная
    
    for(int i=0; *(str+i)!='\0'; i++){
        if (*(str+i)=='B') *(str+i)='_';
    }
   return str;
}
   
    
/*  //c=++
    char*str;
    str+new char [250];
    delete [] str; */
    

//реализуем функцию вывода строки на экран

void outputString (char*s){
    printf ("%s", s);
}
```

Comment: ваш код не компилируется из-за `char ** OpenDataFile (char *filepath, int& n)`.  Вы перепутали язык C с C++.

Comment: получилось выполнить, сейчас прикреплю готовый код

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
while (arrayStrIn[i][j]) { // Цикл до конца строки
    if ( (arrayStrIn[i][j] == '/') && (arrayStrIn[i][j++] == '/'))) {
           arrayStrOut[i][j] = '\0'; // Заканчиваем строку
           break;                    // И завершаем цикл по строке
    } else {
           // Просто копируем символ
            arrayStrOut[i][j] = arrayStrIn[i][j];
    }
}
```

Comment: К сожалению, снова зависает консоль и ничего не происходит(

Comment: @rareSteffe Зависания ловить труднее всего. Но нужно определить как-то место зависания. Место - это оператор цикла, который начинает выполняться бесконечно. Единственный способ - отладочная печать.  Сначала определяем ф-цию, в которой зависает. Для этого, в самом напчале и в самом конце каждой функции вставляем печать (вошли/вышли). Последняя печать "вошли" даст имя функции. Далее по функции раставвляем печать **между** циклами. Так определяем цикл зависания.  После этого внутрь цикла вставляем печать переменной цикла.  И думаем....

Answer (score 0):

Готовый код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char ** OpenDataFile (char *filepath, int& n)
{
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen(filepath, "r");
        if (!fp)
        {
                printf ("Error while openning file\n");
                return NULL;
        }
        
        char buffer[81];
        for(;fgets(buffer,81,fp); n++);
        printf("count = %d",n);
        char **arrayStr;
        arrayStr = (char**)malloc(n*sizeof(char*));
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
        {
            arrayStr[i] = (char*)malloc(81*sizeof(char));
        }
        fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_SET);
        
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
            fgets(arrayStr[i],81,fp);
        }
        fclose(fp);
        return arrayStr;
}

void DeleteSlash (char** arrayStrIn, int n)
{
    char** arrayStrOut;
    arrayStrOut = (char**)malloc(n*sizeof(char*));
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        arrayStrOut[i] = (char*)malloc(81*sizeof(char));
    }
    
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; arrayStrIn[i][j] != '\0'; j++)
        {
 
                if ( (arrayStrIn[i][j] == '/') && (arrayStrIn[i][j+1] == '/') ) 
                {
                    arrayStrIn[i][j] = '\0'; 
                    break;                    
                } 
                else 
                {
                
                    arrayStrOut[i][j] = arrayStrIn[i][j];
                }
        }
    }
}

int WriteResultFile(char * filename, char** arrayStr, int n)
{
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen(filename, "w");
        if (!fp)
        {
            printf ("Error while opennin file\n");
            return -1;
        }
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
            fputs(arrayStr[i], fp);
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    
    char filepath[] = "LABTEXT.txt";
    char filepath2[] = "text.txt";
    int len=0;
    char** text = OpenDataFile(filepath, len);
    DeleteSlash (text, len);
    WriteResultFile (filepath2, text, len);
    return 0;
}
```